# How to only list primary tags in Ghost sidebar

Tags: widget, tags, ghost-blog

My theme is listing all tags in the sidebar, but i'd love to only display the primary tags. Is there a way to archive this without too much coding?

The code looks like this a the moment:

{{!-- Categories Widget --}}

```
{{#get "tags" include="count.posts" limit="all"}}
{{#if tags}}
<div class="gh-sidebar-tags{{#if @custom.html_widget}}{{#unless @site.members_enabled}} with-bottom-border{{/unless}}{{/if}}{{#if @custom.html_widget}}{{#if @site.members_enabled}}{{#if @member}} with-bottom-border{{/if}}{{/if}}{{/if}}">
    <h3 class="gh-sidebar-tags-title">Explore Categories</h3>
    <div class="gh-sidebar-tags-container">
        {{#foreach tags}}
        <div class="gh-sidebar-tag">
            <a class="gh-sidebar-tag-link-wrapper" href="{{url}}">
                <h4 class="gh-sidebar-tag-title">{{name}}</h4>
                <div class="gh-sidebar-tag-count">
                    {{count.posts}}
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        {{/foreach}}
    </div>
</div>
{{/if}}
{{/get}}
```